# Are there any javascript testing frameworks that natively support ES6 imports without babel or another transpiler?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I've developed a node 13.12 application that uses only ES6 style module imports.  Given that it's 2020, I'd like to use a testing framework that can natively support those imports without requiring Babel or any other transpiling.  Does such a framework exist yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this point (May 2020) I have been unable to locate a testing framework that fits the bill. I ended up rolling my own rudimentary one, wasn't as hard as I thought.  Just reimplementing some of the common paradigms like "expect equals" and "expect error". Enough to get some testing done and move on with the real work.